# Turn two columns into one column with two rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**EDITED**:

I have the following dataframe:

| My Code A | My Code B | C | O | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 1B | C1 | O1 | L1 |
| nan | 2B | C2 | nan | L2 |
| 3A | nan | C3 | O3 | nan |

I want to turn it into another dataframe, that looks like this:

| Code | C | O | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | C1 | O1 | L1 |
| 1B | C1 | O1 | L1 |
| 2B | C2 | nan | L2 |
| 3A | C3 | O3 | nan |

This coupling should be *independent* of the column names I called 'C', 'O', and 'L' for now. It can use the first two column names 'My Code A' and 'My Code B'. Some previous answers used specific column names or patterns in column naming.

I have tried to use `pd.melt` but I was not able to get the desired result. It seems like this is quite a standard operation, so it should not be difficult, but I still struggle to make it work. For simlicity, I have defined the dataframe here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'My Code A':['1A', np.nan, '3A'],
        'My Code B':['1B', '2B', np.nan],
        'C':['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
        'O': ['O1', np.nan, 'O3'],
        'L': ['L1', 'L2', np.nan]
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

##### updated answer

Using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
cols = list(df1.columns.difference(['My Code A', 'My Code B']))
out = (df1.melt(cols, value_name='Code')
          .dropna(subset=['Code'])
          .drop(columns='variable')
          [['Code']+cols]  # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
  Code   C    L    O
0   1A  C1   L1   O1
2   3A  C3  NaN   O3
3   1B  C1   L1   O1
4   2B  C2   L2  NaN
```

##### previous answer

You can use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
out = (pd
   .wide_to_long(df1.reset_index(), stubnames=['Code', 'Value'],
                 i='index', j='j', sep=' ', suffix='.*')
   .set_index('Code', append=True)['Value']
   .unstack('j').add_prefix('Value ')
   .reset_index('Code').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Or with a MultiIndex and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = (df1.set_axis(df1.columns.str.split(expand=True), axis=1).stack()
          .set_index('Code', append=True)['Value']
          .unstack(1).add_prefix('Value ')
          .reset_index('Code')
       )
```

Output:

```
  Code Value A Value B
0   1A  Val1 A     NaN
0   1B     NaN  Val1 B
1   2A  Val2 A     NaN
1   2B     NaN  Val2 B
2   3A  Val3 A     NaN
2   3B     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: How would this work for general columns instead of 'Value A' and 'Value B' ? Let's say there are a lot of columns I do not know the name of?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: An example would be a dataframe with columns:
|Code A|Code B|C|O|L|U|M|N|

That would return a dataframe with columns:
|Code|C|O|L|U|M|N|
, where the Code column has entries as specified above. (So the solution should be independent of the name of the remaining columns)

Comment: Please provide an explicit example as edit to your question. In the original question there is a clear mapping between CodeA/ValueA, CodeB/ValueB. What should it be with all those columns?

Comment: Hello @mozway, I edited the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hendrik you're welcome, see update

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @Hendrik you're welcome. I just added an extra step in case you want the columns in order.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
(df.assign(
    Code = df.filter(like='My Code')
    .apply(list, axis=1)).explode('Code')[
        ['Code'] + df.columns[2:].tolist()]
    .dropna(subset='Code'))
```

Output:

```
  Code   C    O    L
0   1A  C1   O1   L1
0   1B  C1   O1   L1
1   2B  C2  NaN   L2
2   3A  C3   O3  NaN
```

Comment: How would this work for general columns instead of 'Value A' and 'Value B' ? Let's say there are a lot of columns I do not know the name of?

Comment: Well, @Hendrik, if you have a dataframe, then you know the names of all columns.

Comment: Just peel off the letters with `letters = set(df1.columns.str[-1:])` if you have more columns than just A and B, then @Hendrick's `concat` will use all of your columns

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment was unclear. I mean, what if my other columns have names unrelated to 'Code A' and 'Code B' and I want to keep all of them. So let's say they are 'col1', 'col2' etc.

Comment: If you have `col1`, `col2`, etc, and, respectively, `Value1`, `Value2`, etc., then use `letters = [1, 2]`. My solution will work in this case, @Hendrik.

Comment: An example would be a dataframe with columns: |Code A|Code B|C|O|L|U|M|N| That would return a dataframe with columns: |Code|C|O|L|U|M|N| , where the Code column has entries as specified above. (So the solution should be independent of the name of the remaining columns)

Comment: It would be best if you edited your question to make that clear, with an example and expected result.

Comment: Hello @PaulS, I edited the question. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think my new solution solves your problem, @Hendrik.

Comment: Welcome, @Hendrik!